# Organize Project Solution w/ Interfaces for Repository

Tags: visual-studio-2010, domain-driven-design, organization, project-organization, ddd-repositories

VS 2010 / C#

Trying to organize a solution and looking for options for naming the project that will host the interfaces for the repository.

I have:
MyProject.Domain

MyProject.WebUI

MyProject.Repositories

MyProject.Interfaces??

So far "Interfaces" is the best name i've come up with, but I don't like it. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It is not too uncommon to see repository interfaces placed in the same assembly as the domain objects, themselves.  This is what Jeffrey Palermo discusses in his series on [The Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).  Personally, I do the same.

As for the reasoning behind it, I believe it is completely logical to define what the repository does in relation to the domain objects.  Consideration as to the behavior of the repository is as heavily weighted as the domain itself, in my opinion.  Assume that you have one team or developer who works on the domain model and defines the repository interfaces after working with the domain expert.  It is their/his/her role to make sure that the knowledge is transferred about how the domain is related to the repositories, but not necessarily the repositories, themselves.

In doing so, handing off this assembly to anyone else on the team, the UoK (Unit of Knowledge, my own term) is constrained to the assembly.  People writing the implementation of the repositories will then code against the transferred knowledge in the assembly.  Since this UoK is unchanging based upon how the repository is implemented, from a data access standpoint, it logically goes into another assembly.